# How to create an alertdialog that hides its choice items depending on time

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm implementing a singleChoiceItems alert dialog in android but i want to have a check such that some items in the array wont show depending on time.

Is this possible or is there any method i could use in place of the alert dialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example how to check the time and change the items if "true". 
Dialog box is an object, you can call its properties by calling biulder.* in different locations.

```
String[] colurs ={"Red","Blue","Green"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Pick Colour")
        .setItems(colurs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                // of the selected item
            }
        });
if(currentThreadTimeMillis()>1000){
    colurs[0]="New1";
    colurs[1]="New2";

    builder.setTitle("Pick Colour").setItems(colurs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
            // of the selected item
        }
    });
}
builder.create();
builder.show();
```